# How to extract text from PDF?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I'm creating a React Application with NodeJS and it needs to get some text from a PDF that the user upload.

I already tried to use: pdf-parse, pdf2json, pdf.js and react-pdf-js. The file should be selected by the user, and all those libraries use a Path to acess the file. What should I do?
PS1: I'm using a input type='file' button to get the file.

The code must work both NodeJS and Web Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. First I create a regular html input.

```
<input type='file'/>
```

I'm using React, so I use `onChange` attribute in place of `id`.
So, when the user enters with the file, a function is activated and I use the following code to get the file:

```
const file = event.target.files[0];
```

`file` not has a path, which is used by PDF.JS to get the real file.
Then I use a `FileReader` to convert the file int a Array of bits (I guess):

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
```

Then we set a function at `fileReader.onload` the function can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ourcodeworld/9s3hpbu2/)

```
fileReader.onload = function() {...}
```

Finally we do this:

```
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Important PS: `pdf.pdfInfo` must be replaced with `pdf` at new PDF.JS versions.

Thanks for helping.

Extra PS: To use `pdfjsLib` as PDFJS in React I did this in `index.html` file:

```
window.PDFJS = pdfjsLib
```

Comment: Which library are you using: pdf-parse, pdf2json, pdf.js, or react-pdf-js?
Where does pdf.pdfInfo come into play?

Comment: @CuriousChad I'm using pdf.js

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't upload any code snippet, so my answer is according to this scenario

You can see this example, this is perfect example for "HOW TO USE `pdf.js`"

http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/

And this is the code on `git`
https://github.com/hubgit/hubgit.github.com/tree/master/2011/11/pdftotext

but I think you have to make some changes according to your requirement

Enjoy..

Comment: That's the point, pdf.js requires a path to file, and how I said, I need to run on web.

Comment: What do you need, if you want to parse pdf in nodeJs(On Server side), then also you have to give the path of file!!! Now I not sure what is your problem actually :P